# ReactJS How to change value of object stored in state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

All code will be below my question and explanation.

So what I am trying to do is update my state which is in a grandparent class, this is done for reasons to do with files, I am also using Material-UI for the text boxes.
And I'm also writing Redux without Redux, Because I can just if you see some strange things.

My grandparent class state looks like this:

```
state = {
  value: 0,
  application: {
    ApplicationPK: '',
    Person: [
      {
        PersonPK: '',
        FullName: '',
        TitleFK: '',
        Forename: '',
        MiddleNames: '',
        Surname: '',
        DateOfBirth: '',
        HomeTelephone: '',
        MobileTelephone: '',
        EmailAddress: '',
        LoanPurposeFK: '',
        MaritalStatusFK: '',
        Addresses: [
          {
            FlatNumber: '',
            BuildingName: '',
            BuildingNumber: '',
            Street: '',
            District: '',
            Town: '',
            County: '',
            Postcode: '',
            ResidentialStatusFK: '',
            DateMovedIn: '',
            IsCurrentAddress: '',
            AddressPK: '',
          },
        ],
        Employment: [
          {
            EmploymentStatusFK: '',
            Employer: '',
            JobTitle: '',
            Telephone: '',
            MonthlyPay: '',
            IsPaidByBACS: '',
            PayFrequencyFK: '',
            DayOfMonth: '',
            DayOfWeek: '',
            NextPayDate: '',
            FollowingPayDate: '',
            DateStarted: '',
            Postcode: '',
            EmploymentPK: '',
            Website: '',
          },
        ],
        BankAccount: [
          {
            Name: '',
            Sortcode: '',
            AccountNumber: '',
            IsAccountHolder: '',
            IsJointHolder: '',
            IsSoleAuthoriseDebits: '',
            IsPrimary: '',
            IsActive: '',
            BankAccountPK: '',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I know its long but thats because it errors because mui text boxes dont like null values on load.

this is how im changing the state at the moment but its adding it as a value at the top level of the state and i want it to obviously replace the value that is inside person. this function is in the same class as the state obviously

```
 handleChangeType = event => {
   this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
 }
```

and Finally the Mui Text Box looks like this:

```
<Input
   defaultValue={this.props.state.application.Person[0].Forename}
   className={classes.input}
   onChange={this.props.handleChangeType}
   name="Forename"
   inputProps={{
     'aria-label': 'Description',
   }}
/>
```

TL:DR: How do i update the correct value in the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I  know its long but thats because it errors because mui text boxes dont like null values on load.

To avoid initializing a bunch of empty strings everywhere, you could just do:

```
defaultValue={((this.props.state.application || {}).Person[0] || {}).Forename || ""}
```

---

As per updating the correct state variable, I would use a different handler for each category. You must also bear in mind that your state variable here is the `Person` array. If you want to update anything within it, you need to pass a new array to the state. Finally, you seem to want to be able to have multiple users inside your `Persons` array, but your event handlers aren't given any info of which user you want to update field X or Y.

For example:

```
handleChangeType = (userIndex, name, event) => {
  let person = Object.assign({}, this.state.Persons[userIndex]);  //shallow-copy
  person[name] = event.target.value
  this.setState({Person: person });
}
```

For each object or array that's nestled, you'll need to create a copy, change the copy and then replace the original with the copy.

Comment: Thank you that helps but how do i set the one value of the object in the state as i keep overwriting the whole state or its sitting at the top level of the state so it doesnt update in the box.

Comment: so i would need a handlechangepersons and so on for each different object

Comment: @andrewwilson, you could, yes. The problem here is with how your data is structured. It makes updating the state correctly a bit of a pain. Consider simplifying the structure, if possible.

Comment: so you would say remove the application brackets and just have persons at the same level as where application would have been in the state

Comment: is it possible to pass variables to a function through another class like i am doing or is that not suggested. Sorry its quite a complex system im writing here.

Comment: Its giving me unexpected use of name and event in my two classes that are under the one in the grandparent class why is this, im trying to pass through the values or do i just write `this.props.handleChangeType`. And when i dont try and pass them through it says `Cannot read property value of undefinded talking about target` How do i fix this too.

Comment: Still isnt working i cant seem to get it to work when passing it completely through a class without touching it??

Comment: Yeah target is undefined when it gets back to handleChangeType in the top level component

Comment: `this.props.state.application || {}).Person[0] || {}).Forename || ""` what is this called so i can research more about it

Comment: Too many questions Andrew. Don't take this the wrong way but this isn't a helpdesk. Open new questions and ping me here instead with the new link if you'd like my attention. I can quickly comment on your last question though: short-circuit evaluation. Basically tries the existence each of the properties and if it doesn't exist it creates a new empty one in its place. This is a workaround to prevent js throwing an error. Again ask a new question if this isn't clear. Good luck!